# Google colaboratory: Cannot import 'LRN2D' from utils

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am trying out the Python Notebook https://github.com/TessFerrandez/research-papers/tree/master/facenet
on Google Colaboratory.

I cant even run the first block on code because I get this error:

ImportError
Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()

```
  1 from model import create_model
```

/content/model.py in ()

```
 12 import utils
 13 from utils import LRN2D
 14 
 15 def create_model():
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'LRN2D'

I already !pip installed utils. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Don't `!pip install utils` but use this instead.

```
!git clone https://github.com/TessFerrandez/research-papers.git
%cd research-papers/facenet
from model import create_model
```

Here, the `utils` mean the local `utils.py`, not some utils library of some other projects